# Database BCNF and functional dependency

Tags: mysql, database, bcnf

[image: Problem]

I am given this table and am asked to put it into BCNF form

I am given no functional dependencies

Here is what I have been trying so far

So I made the assumption based on the table that student -> class AND instructor, class -> campus would be the FDs of this relation

Based on that I used student, instructor -> student, instructor, class, campus for the primary key.

After this my understanding of BCNF kind of breaks down as I'm not sure how you can join a 3 row table with a 4 row table but... this is what I was thinking.  If anyone could help me correct my understanding I would appreciate it.  Thank you.

[image: answer i attempted]

Comment: Read about BCNF first.

Comment: I did, thats why I am here